# Google Scripts - How to call the correct sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, dashboard

I´m learning how to use the Google Scripts, I saw a video on the youtube and I wrote this code based on the video. It will be a dashboard, but the problem I have is: In this spreadsheet, I have more than one Sheet. How can I "tell" the code which sheet it would have to check? In my case the Sheet ID is 8.

I think this would be the only "mistake" in the code!

Thanks for helping!

```
function doGet() {
  // Identify the spreadsheet where the data is stored.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AjizIuAuEzaydFlsRDRrTkZSekROaWNZNV9QbjRDdUE')
  var data = ss.getDataRange();

  // Create all the filters
  var clienteFilter = Charts.newNumberRangeFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(1).build();
  var pedidoFilter = Charts.newNumberRangeFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(2).build();
  var necessidadeFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(3).build();
  var entregaFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(4).build();
  var notaconsultorFilter = Charts.newNumberRangeFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(5).build();
  var notaentregadorFilter = Charts.newNumberRangeFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(6).build();
  var recomendariaFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(8).build();
  var atencaoFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(9).build();
  var servicosFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(10).build();
  var entregadorFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(11).build();

  // Create all the charts
  var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
  .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([11,6]))
  .build();

  // Create the dashboard
  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data)
  .bind([clienteFilter, pedidoFilter, necessidadeFilter, entregaFilter, notaconsultorFilter, notaentregadorFilter, recomendariaFilter, atencaoFilter, servicosFilter, entregadorFilter],[pieChart])
  .build();

  // Create the webapp and bind together the filters and charts
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var filterPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var chartPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  filterPanel.add(clienteFilter).add(pedidoFilter).add(necessidadeFilter).add(entregaFilter).add(notaconsultorFilter).add(notaentregadorFilter).add(recomendariaFilter).add(atencaoFilter).add(servicosFilter).add(entregadorFilter).setSpacing(10);
  chartPanel.add(pieChart).setSpacing(10);

  // Format the dashboard layout
  dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(filterPanel).add(chartPanel));
  app.add(dashboard);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code , `ss` comes for a spreadSheet object, which is -way of speaking - the "parent" of the included sheets.

This class (spreadsheet object) has a couple of methods to get sheets that are described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet), for example `getSheetByName('name of the sheet')` or `getSheets()` which returns an array of sheet objects. In this case you can chose which one you use with `getSheets()[number]`

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help!
So, should my could be:

function doGet() {
  // Identify the spreadsheet where the data is stored.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AjizIuAuEzaydFlsRDRrTkZSekROaWNZNV9QbjRDdUE').getSheetId(8)
  var data = ss.getDataRange();

Because I tried this, but I get an error.

Comment: no, .getSheet‌​Id(8) is not valid... if it is the 8th sheet in your spreadsheet use getSheets()[7] but preferably use the sheet **name** in case sheet is moved .

Comment: Thanks one more time Serge insas, it worked the way you suggested!
But the only thing I see in my dashboard when I deploy the web app is: Object type does not match column type.
Do u have any idea of what to do to correct this?

Comment: But the only thing I see in my dashboard when I deploy the web app is: Object type does not match column type. Do u have any idea of what to do to correct this?

Comment: This is another question about charts... I'm not a chart user...and please don't "chain" questions.